# How to set the values of a new column in dataframe based on the other column and a key?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset as the follows that includes player's attributes for each match. The dataset is in Pandas Dataframe format and it sorted by date for each characterId in descending order.

```
characterId  date               kills deaths matchResult   
200          3-5-2014-22:30:10  10      12     0
300          4-4-2014-23:30:10  10      13     1
400          1-2-2014-17:30:10  9       10     1
201          3-5-2014-22:20:05  11      16     0
301          1-4-2014-20:20:05  18      15     1
```

I want to add a new column (`nextResult`) that contains the value of `matchResult` of the last match. The new dataframe should look as follows:

```
characterId  date               kills deaths matchResult   nextResult
200          3-5-2014-22:30:10  10      12     0             nan
300          4-4-2014-23:30:10  10      13     1             0
400          1-2-2014-17:30:10  9       10     1             1 
201          3-5-2014-22:20:05  11      16     0             nan 
301          1-4-2014-20:20:05  18      15     1             0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `shift` and `where` to check to see whether the characterId has restarted.

```
 df['nextResult'] = df.shift(1)['matchResult'].where(df.characterid.diff().fillna(0).ge(0))
```

Output:

```
   characterid               date  kills  deaths  matchResult  nextResult
0          200  3-5-2014-22:30:10     10      12            0         NaN
1          300  4-4-2014-23:30:10     10      13            1         0.0
2          400  1-2-2014-17:30:10      9      10            1         1.0
3          201  3-5-2014-22:20:05     11      16            0         NaN
4          301  1-4-2014-20:20:05     18      15            1         0.0
```

---

```
df['nextResult'] = df.shift(1)['matchResult'].where(df.characterid.gt(df.shift(1).fillna('').characterid.astype(str)))
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution. I tried it, but it shows the following error:


    ` features.shift(1)['matchResult'].where(features.characterId.diff().fillna(0).ge(0))
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 1459, in diff
    result = algos.diff(_values_from_object(self), periods)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\algorithms.py", line 1251, in diff
    out_arr[res_indexer] = arr[res_indexer] - arr[lag_indexer]
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'`

Comment: Are you CharacterId's always integers or could there be some letters in there?

Comment: The `characterId` is a string.

Comment: Yes, the diff doesn't work well with string.  We can use characterid.astype(int).diff() if you don't expect anything other than numbers in characterid.

Comment: The output is always nan. `characterId` is 19 digits in string format such as '2305843009218992152'.

Answer (score 0):

Simply access the data frame as if it were a dictionary:

```
import numpy as np # for np.NaN (or use NaN = float('nan'))
df = pd.DataFrame({ ... }) # your dataframe possibly from a CSV
df['nextResult'] = [np.NaN, 0, 1, np.NaN, 0]
```

For an intro to pandas see https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html

Comment: Scott obviously had more info on how to create 'nextResult'.